# What is reason behind occasional functioning of jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide an icon if that icon is clicked by user, here is what I am trying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
                <script>
                        $("#container").on("click" , function(){
            $("#container").delay("slow").hide();
            });
                        </script>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device width" initial scale="1.0" />
            <title>Experiment</title>
            <style>
                #container{
                    position:fixed;
                    top:5%;
                    left:5%;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="container">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-4x"></i>
                    </div>
                </body>
        </html>
```

But it is not working.
Then I replaced `#container` with `window` in `jquery section` , that is: this time I was trying to hide icon on `window click` and it is working perfectly! I am new in this field and I am confused.
Take a look at script where `#container` container is replaced by `window`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
                <script>
                        $(window).on("click" , function(){
            $("#container").delay("slow").hide();
            });
                        </script>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device width" initial scale="1.0" />
            <title>Experiment</title>
            <style>
                #container{
                    position:fixed;
                    top:5%;
                    left:5%;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="container">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-4x"></i>
                    </div>
                </body>
        </html>
```

> Sorry in advance, if you are not comfortable with, me merging all scripts in one segment!

Comment: in the first script, replace the `$("#container").delay("slow").hide();` line with `$(this).delay("slow").hide();`, i think what is happening is jquery searching for #container inside the #container

Comment: Dear `Ramon` still it is not working!